# Find Regex for text in Visual Studio solution file

Tags: regex, .net-core

I want to find the projects included in a solution file. I constructed a regex for this purpose when I run the regex in online compiler it works fine but in my local application it does not work. Here are both the regex

Regex on My machine:

```
@"Project\(""(\{.*\})""\)\s*=\s*""(myproject)""\s*,\s*""(.*)""\s*,\s*""(.*)""[\s*\n*\s*]EndProject"
```

Regex online Compiler:

```
Project\("(\{.*\})"\)\s*=\s*"(myproject)"\s*,\s*"(.*)"\s*,\s*"(.*)"[\s*\n*\s*]EndProject
```

My code:

```
Regex Pattern = new Regex(pattern);
var inputLines = File.ReadAllText(path);
var matches = Pattern.Matches(inputLines);
```

Sample Text

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.29613.14
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "myproject", "myproject.csproj", "{96C046DE-705D-4984-9414-124B6A6EA28E}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {96C046DE-705D-4984-9414-124B6A6EA28E}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {96C046DE-705D-4984-9414-124B6A6EA28E}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {96C046DE-705D-4984-9414-124B6A6EA28E}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {96C046DE-705D-4984-9414-124B6A6EA28E}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {B766FA40-EBEF-4E79-A5B1-04BE348D4793}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: show how you run it in your local application?

Comment: Regex Pattern = new Regex(pattern);
var inputLines = File.ReadAllText(path);
var matches = Pattern.Matches(inputLines);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `[\s*\n*\s*]` (equal to `[\s*]`) only matches 1 char, either a whitespace or `*`. In your file, you must have CRLF (`"\r\n"`) line endings and the two-char combination can't be matched with that pattern.

Note that most regex online compilers only have LF as line ending sequence, that is why you got a match with your pattern there. You may use [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test .NET patterns against text containing CRLF endings (no affiliation with the Web site on my part).

You should use

```
var Pattern = new Regex(@"Project\(""({.*?})""\)\s*=\s*""(myproject)""\s*,\s*""(.*?)""\s*,\s*""(.*?)""\s*EndProject");
var inputLines = File.ReadAllText(path);
var matches = Pattern.Matches(inputLines);
```

Note the `\s*EndProject` part where `\s*` matches any 0 or more whitespace characters. If there is a line break for sure, you may also use `\s+` to match any 1 or more whitespace characters.

I also changed all greedy `.*` patterns with their lazy (non-greedy) counterparts for better performance.